# How do I change the font in a WPF RichTextBox in one Form using another Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, combobox, richtextbox

I'm trying to control RichTextBox font from another form.
Here's what I've tried in the Second Form:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Agency FB") ;
        {
            Form1.richTextBox1.Font.Replace = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif");
        }
    }
```

I expected that it would work like that but it tells me two things:

> 'Form1.richTextBox1' is inaccessible due to it's protection level
>
> 'Font' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not allowed to access richTextBox1 from the other form, if you want to access it you might want to add a public function to Form1 with a parameter for a Font and call that instead. Also, I am pretty sure you'll need an object reference for it instead of calling it statically. So you would need to find a way to get the instance of Form1.

Also, Font does not contain a constructor with 1 argument. To fix this you simply need to specify a font size (as float) so the constructor would look like this: 
`new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11f)`.